# pandas derive missing values in column based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
box type len
abc 20HE nan
def 20GE 20
ghi 40HC 40
jkl 20HE 20
mno 40HC nan
pqr 40GE nan
stu 20GC 20
```

The missining values in 'len' can be replaced by the string column 'type', by taking the first two characters of the value in 'type' to a int value 20 or 40.

desired output:

```
box type len
abc 20HE 20
def 20GE 20
ghi 40HC 40
jkl 20HE 20
mno 40HC 40
pqr 40GE 40
stu 20GC 20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `np.where` function of numpy here, please try following. Where `df` is your dataframe.

```
df['len'] = np.where(df['len'].isnull(),df['type'].str[:2],df['len'])
df
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `.where` function.

```
df['len'] = df['len'].where(df['len'].notnull(),df['type'].str[:2])
df
```